# CloudFormation LaunchConfiguration SSM Association

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-cloudformation

I see that it's now possible to create EC2 instances bootstrapped with SSM association(s):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-document.html

But I don't see analogous properties exposed on Launch Configurations...

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html

Is this just not possible yet or is there a way of getting SSM associations added automatically to EC2 instances launched via a Launch Configuration?

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to just call the [CreateAssociation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ssm/latest/APIReference/API_CreateAssociation.html) API directly when each instance is booted. You could use a [Auto Scaling Event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/cloud-watch-events.html) to invoke a Lambda function, or (probably easier) add a shell-script line into your Launch Configuration's UserData that invokes the API through the AWS CLI ([`aws ssm create-association`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/create-association.html)), retrieving the currently-running instance ID through [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html):

```
aws ssm create-association \
  --name mySSMDocumentName \
  --instance-id $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
```

You'll need to provide the Launch Configuration an IAM instance profile with "ssm:CreateAssociation" permissions and also provide the AWS CLI with the current region (either exported to the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable, or with an explicit `--region` parameter.)

Comment: Yes but I was hoping for something inbuilt

Comment: Specifically, for me to consider this an answer, I need to be able to provision which specific SSM documents the EC2 instance can associate itself to. This becomes a chicken or the egg game if the SSM document itself is created in the same template as the Instance Profile, Role, and LaunchConfiguration. Basically, I need a way to say, EC2 instances in this LaunchConfiguration can perform SSM association by themselves...but ONLY to this one SSM document that is part of the stack. Further, I can't have the launcher of the stack to have total rights to create new policies.

Comment: To restrict permissions to a single SSM document, replace `*` with `arn:aws:ssm:region:account-id:document/document_name` in the value of the "Resource" element in your Instance Profile's policy definition for the `ssm:CreateAssociation` action. If you don't want to give your stack launcher rights to create new IAM policies, either create the policy in a separate stack or via the AWS console, then enter the instance profile's ARN (`arn:aws:iam::account:instance-profile/instance-profile-name`) in your LaunchConfiguration directly.